# Cannot open local source file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

As seen in the image below I am getting the "cannot open course file" compiler error.
I have looked around SO and Google and found many other issues like this but mostly trying to use an external library and simply not using <> instead of "" in the include, or not providing the entire path.

Then I found this thread with my exact issue that has got me worried http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/258649-error-cannot-open-source-file/

I am pretty sure I have written the correct syntax as this includes correctly in the Arduino IDE, so, what have I done wrong with this project? I have tried putting the header files in the Header Files folder but it still does not find them. Could this be a project setting issue?

I do have the Arduino plugin installed but did create a new normal C++ project, as seen that the build buttons are disabled.

I am trying to practice using [this](http://www.trenki.net/content/view/17/1/) FixedPoint library in a clean new C++ project.

[image: Screenshot of project]

Comment: You are showing the Solution Explorer, while it doesn't represent the actual file location in the file system. Open the folder, within file explorer, where `FixedPoint.cpp` is located, and confirm that `fixed_class.h` is located in the same folder.

Comment: Oh I see, It did not copy them. I tried dragging and dropping and using the Add menu under Source File so why didn't it add properly? Or at least add a reference to pretend?

Comment: Why should it? That's how VS works with C++.

Comment: Then how are the files "added" in any way if I can't use them at all?